# Get endorsement from multiple peer of the same Org in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using hyperledger fabric V2.4 and I'm trying to enforce that a transaction in a private data collection should be endorsed by at least N peers in order to be accepted.

I've seen many answers like "Use `AND('Org1MSP.member', 'Org1MSP.member')` or `OutOf(2, 'Org1MSP.member', 'Org1MSP.member')` but the result is always this:

```
EndorseError: 10 ABORTED: failed to collect enough transaction endorsements, see attached details for more info
    ...blablabla stacktrace....
    ... 2 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  code: 10,
  details: [],
  cause: Error: 10 ABORTED: failed to collect enough transaction endorsements, see attached details for more info 

 ....blablabla more stacktrace....
  {
    code: 10,
    details: 'failed to collect enough transaction endorsements, see attached details for more info',
    metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: [Map], options: {} }
  },
  transactionId: 'a215f6708df6658925e4fbeed3d964efa8e60759fde76d4dcd2b54199ef439e9'
}
```

(it is very funny that the attached details are "see attached details")

I think it was possible in hyperledger 1.X as all of these answers are like 3/5 years old, and now i'm trying to find a way to implement it in HF 2.4.

Here below it is the definition of one of the collections

```json
     ...
    {
        "name": "sessionCollection_Org1MSP",
        "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member')",
        "requiredPeerCount": 0,
        "maxPeerCount": 1,
        "blockToLive": 1000,
        "memberOnlyRead": true,
        "memberOnlyWrite": true,
        "endorsementPolicy": {
            "signaturePolicy": "AND('Org1MSP.member', 'Org1MSP.member')" //doesn't work
        }
    },
    ...
```

There is a way to do it or is it not possible anymore?

Comment: Just as an aside, the "attached details" are `details: []` (in other words, there don't appear to be any)

Comment: It's worth checking your Gateway peer logs for more detail on what went wrong from that end. If not already enabled, you might want to turn on debug logging for the peer: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging-control.html